# Compare User Input Text to CSV File C#

Tags: c#, file, csv, text, compare

If I have user input from a text box in c#, and have a CSV file of words for example with user input being: "Wow that's cool LOL" and the CSV file:

LOL Laughing Out Loud

ROFL Rolling On Floor Laughing

How would I compare the input text to find any matches in the file? How would I load the file?

Comment: How are the fields separated in the csv file?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
string input = "Wow that's cool LOL";
string[] splitArray = input.Split();
bool ifFound = File.ReadLines("yourCVSFilePath.csv")
                .Any(line => splitArray.Any(line.Contains));
```

It is doing:

- Split the input into an array of words to be compared individually.
- Loads the file line by line (lazy loading)
- Compare to see if any words in the split array matches any word in the line.

If you want to perform string comparison ignoring case then you can do:

```
bool ifFound = File.ReadLines("yourCVSFilePath.csv")
                .Any(line => 
                        splitArray.Any(sa => 
                                    line.IndexOf(sa, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1));
```

Comment: A csv contains normally multiple fields, you are using a substring search with `line.Contains` instead of only checking against the fields. So a value `lollipop` would also match against `LOL`.

Comment: Tim, this more looks like a text file, then a CSV, although there are multiple fields, *(probably separated by comma)*, but from the question it looks like that OP is going to do the comparison on each field, and not just a specific field.

Comment: Sure, but it seems that OP wants to check all fields but i assume that it should be a full match and not a partial. Look at my example lollipop.

Comment: so are you saying that every word in input should exists in CSV ? and not just a single word ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `File.ReadLines` to read the lines from the csv file and LINQ to filter them:

```
string input = "Wow that's cool LOL";
string[] words = input.Split();

char delimiter = '\t';  // for example
IEnumerable<string> matchingLines = File.ReadLines("yourCVSFilePath.csv")
    .Where(line => words.Intersect(line.Split(delimiter)).Any())
    .ToList(());
```

The `Intersect`...`Any` approach is an optimized version of this alternative query:

```
......
.Where(line => words.Any(word => line.Split(delimiter).Contains(word)))
```